# Getting Type 'InteractionStatus' is not assignable to type '"startup"' using node-browser and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, msal.js, msal

I was using node-browser 2.5 with javascript/typescript, based on this vue sample project.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/vue3-sample-app

Then I upgraded to msal v3 and followed their upgrade guide which was simple, and it only had me add in `await msalInstance.initialize();` right after making a new instance of `PublicClientApplication`. However, on this file now

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/vue3-sample-app/src/plugins/msalPlugin.ts

I am getting a typescript error.

[image]

Which leads me to think there was another breaking change. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer is posted here. Take a look.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/6706